# how to make a java console menu and call different java file in the project using those options?

Tags: java

I have created different .java files in my project. Now I want to create a console menu with options to run those classes seperately.

```
public class ConsoleMenuDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Local variable
int swValue;

// Display menu graphics
System.out.println("============================");
System.out.println("|   MENU SELECTION DEMO    |");
System.out.println("============================");
System.out.println("| Options:                 |");
System.out.println("|        1. Option 1       |");
System.out.println("|        2. Option 2       |");
System.out.println("|        3. Exit           |");
System.out.println("============================");
swValue = Keyin.inInt(" Select option: ");

// Switch construct
switch (swValue) {
case 1:
  System.out.println("Option 1 selected");   // This is where I want to call the class
  break;
case 2:
  System.out.println("Option 2 selected");  // this is where I want to call the class
  break;
case 3:
  System.out.println("Exit selected");
  break;
default:
  System.out.println("Invalid selection");
  break; // This break is not really necessary
}


 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "call the class", but rather call a class' constructor or static methods. Presumably, you have other public classes with their own constructors and instance methods. If that's the case, just make sure all your classes are in the same package and you can simply then write:

```
case 1:
  System.out.println("Option 1 selected");   // This is where I want to call the class
  Class1 class1 = new Class1();
  class1.doSomething();
  break;
case 2:
  System.out.println("Option 2 selected");  // this is where I want to call the class
  Class2 class2 = new Class2();
  class2.doSomethingElse();
  break;
```

Comment: Okay. Now I have made Jar files and classes were in same package. how should I run them in case1, case2 etc.